# Why do I obtain a zero net force in tension for a torque happening on a bar supported on its center?

Tags: trigonometry, vectors, physics, classical-mechanics

The problem is as follows:

> A cable goes across points A and B such that the bar will not slide as
>   indicated in the figure from below. The mass of the bar is $2.5\,kg$.
>   Assuming that the surface has no friction, find the tension on the
>   wire so that the system remains in mechanical equilibrium.

[image: Sketch of the problem]

The alternatives given in my book are as follows:

$\begin{array}{ll}
1.&12\,N\\
2.&10\,N\\
3.&14\,N\\
4.&16\,N\\
5.&18\,N\\
\end{array}$

What I attempted to do to solve this problem was to put the reaction force due the weight on the midpoint and using the point on $C$ as rotation axis. Therefore taking the distance for each force to that point.

[image: Sketch of the solution]

Because the Normal force is not given I assumed that it was the resultant from the weight and the wire pulling to the wall as indicated in the diagram. Considering the direction of such force I did the following:

$N=w\sin 53^{\circ}+T\sin 37^{\circ}$

Then:

$-5N+10\left(T\sin37^{\circ}\right)+5\left(w\sin 53^{\circ}\right)=0$

$-5\left(w\sin 53^{\circ}+10T\sin 37^{\circ}\right)+5\left(w\sin 53^{\circ}\right)=0$

$-5\frac{4w}{5}-5\frac{3T}{5}+10T\frac{3}{5}+5\frac{4w}{5}=0$

Because $w= 2.5 \times 10 = 25$

The preceding equation would become into:

$-4 \times 25 - 3T + 6T + 4 \times 25 =0$

$3T=0$

$T= 0\,N$

Therefore I end up obtaining a zero force for the tension. What could I be doing wrong?. Can somebody help me with the appropiate calculation for the tension using my approach?.

Comment: Where's the cable?

Comment: You forgot that there is a normal force acting at the rod at A as well.

Comment: The normal force **is** given: $N=mg·sin(53º)$. It does not depend on T. But T does depend on N.

Comment: @Ripi2 That's exactly the source of my confusion why it doesn't depend on $T$? Can you explain to me this?. There's also the tension pulling the bar at the bottom, should I account for that force as well?.

Comment: The first action over the bar is gravity, pure vertical. The other action is the cable, whose tension is pure horizontal, it cannot balance the gravity. So the only case is that gravity is balanced with the Normal at the support. But then after substitution of gravity with N and perpendicular to N (call it "S") N is balanced but not "S", which makes the bar to slide. And then comes the wire to action, through the force "T". If the bar was horizontal then $T=0$, no need to equilibrate anything. If the cable was not horizontal then reaction at support (N) may be not the same.

Answer (score 1):

Characterizing

$$
\cases{
W=(0,-m g)\\
T=t_0(1,0)\\
V = v_0(0,1)\\
F_C=f_0(-\sin\alpha,\cos\alpha)\\
x_C=\frac{h}{\tan\alpha}\\
y_C = h\\
x_G = \frac L2 \cos\alpha\\
y_G = \frac L2 \sin\alpha\\
G=(x_G,y_G)\\
C=(x_C,y_C)\\
O=(0,0)
}
$$

we have now the equilibrium equations

$$
\cases{
V+T+W+F_C=0\\
(C-O)\times F_C + (G-O)\times W = 0
}
$$

Three equations and three unknowns $t_0,v_0, f_0$

Answer (score 0):

With A as the pivot point, establish the equilibrium equations below,

$$T = N\cos 53,\>\>\>\>\>N = mg \sin 53$$

to obtain the tension

$$T = mg \cdot\cos 53\cdot\sin 53 = (2.5\times10)\cdot \frac 35\cdot\frac45 = 12N$$

Comment: Why $T=N\cos 53^{\circ}$ and $N=mg\sin 53^{\circ}$? I'm trying to look at my diagram but I can't find the way to make those equations.